# How to change the Android ImageButton's image from Drawable folder when the app it's started, whit an intent?

Tags: android, select, drawable, imagebutton

Hi guys can you help me?

I want to allow the App's users to change the ImageButton's image choosing from the files(png) of the Drawable folder, I think I need to create an Inten.
I associate this "event" after an OnLongClickListener.

How does this translate into code?

thank you very much!
kind regards

Comment: so you have an imageview and it needs to be updated programmatically based on a button press. am i right?

Comment: Yes sir, when the user click on Imagebutton he can choose the ImageButton's image between the png files in the Drawable folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the button click you can start a new activity for result, in this activity you can show all of the images in the drawable folder
To start an activity use:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MostraDrawableActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(i, 7412);
    }

});
```

In MostraDrawableActivity,t o get the name of all the images in drawable folder you can use this:

```
Field[] drawables = <your packagen name>.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
        System.out.println("R.drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With the names you can fill a ListView using a simplearrayadapter, then when the user clicks on a list element you have to do:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("nomeDrawableScelto",listViewElementName);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);     
finish();
```

In this way the current activity closes, and "passes back" to the original activity the name of the choosen drawable

Now we can go back to our original activity when we have to override the OnActivityResult Method like this, and set the button's background image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 7412) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){      
                      b.setBackgroundResource(getResources().getIdentifier(data.getStringExtra("nomeDrawableScelto"), "drawable",getPackageName()));
         }

      }
    }//onActivityResult
```

**EDIT TO FILL THE LISTVIEW**

```
ArrayList<String> foto = new ArrayList<String>();
Field[] drawables = <your packagen name>.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
        foto.add("R.drawable." + f.getName());
        //System.out.println("R.drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



// Create the array adapter to bind the array to the listView
final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(  this, 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            foto 
                        );
myListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: Grazie Alessandro,
il mio problema è un po' diverso, vorrei che l'utente potesse scegliere le immagini dalla cartella drawable proprio dell'ImageButton cliccato, il mio inglese fa pena,
gentilissimo

Comment: ah ho capito..in italiano facciamo prima! :-) con il comando che ti ho dato io riesci solo a impostare un immagine di sfondo, prendendola dalla cartella drawable, conoscendone il nome ma non l'id... ti ho modificato il codice per impostare lo sfondo del bottone... Come vorresti che l'utente visualizzasse l'elenco di immagini tra cui scegliere?

Comment: Grazie, guarda aprendo una nuova pagina,sarebbe perfetto, dove l'utente vede le immagini caricate da me, comunque sulla visualizzazione non ho preferenze, vorrei solo dare la possibilità all'utente di poter scegliere tra alcuni png nella cartella drawable.
Su youtube c'è un tutorial,ma li le carica dalla galleria del telefono, grazie mille!

Comment: ho modificato la mia risposta..non so se tutti i passaggi siano chiari, ho dato alcune cose per scontate...se serve aiuto scrivi pure...

Comment: Sono pessimo, alla riga Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields(); mi da questo errore, Type mismatch: cannot convert from Field[] to Format.Field[]

Comment: Comunque era proprio quello che cercavo, grazie veramente!
sono alle prime armi...

Comment: controlla gli import...che importi la riga giusta:import java.lang.reflect.Field;  cancellale tutte e premi ctrl + shift + O, eclipse reimporta tutto giusto..inoltre sostituisci android con il nome del package della tua app..

Comment: alla riga:
Field[] drawables = <your packagen name>.R.drawable.class.getFields();
ho provato a mettere il nome della cartella dove ho le immagini,ma mi da errore

Comment: devi scriverci il nome del package, lo trovi nella prima riga di ogni classe del progetto... package <nome package>;

Comment: Alessandro, ti ringrazio,
devo studiare un bel po',adesso ci sono problemi con l'ArrayAdapter... :D
il tuo aiuto è utilissimo!!!

Comment: Di niente...sull'array adapter trovi un sacco di esempi in giro... cerca tipo SimpleArrayAdapter...

Comment: ah se la mia risposta ti è stata di aiuto la segneresti come corretta? :-D grazie mille

Comment: Buongiorno Alessandro,
sai per caso come poter creare l'arrey adapter partendo dalla variabile Field, se vuoi creo la domanda per darti maggiore reputazione, grazie

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer,

```
ImageView iv=(Imageview)findViewById(R.id.imageView1); //importing that imageview into code to set programmatically

public void button(View view){

iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.png1);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Yogamurthy, but I want to allow user to change the image from res/drawable in app

Comment: how the user will change it. do you have a button or spinner or something else?

Comment: There is an ImageButton, and after click the user can choose a new ImageButton's image from res/drawable folder, very thanks!

Comment: how the user will see the list of images in drawable folder?

Comment: is it pictures selected on random?

Comment: The user can choose the pictures in the folder, but I don't know how the user will see the list of images in drawable folder.
On youtube there is a looklike function,but in that example He load the pictures from Gallery phone.

Comment: ok then use a switch case and increment the number for every button press. place your pictures in the case statement. so when user selects the button the pictures will appear in sequence.